# How to use volley on android with LoginDataSource created by android studio Activity login wizard?

Tags: android, api, android-volley, datasource

I'm just starting building an app on android and I try to create a simple test app to login to a REST api using volley.
As a first experiment I just created an Activity using Android Studio activity wizard and I create a "Login Activity".
After digging around on code, I land on "LoginDataSource" that is the code responsible for the authentication and for creating the application "internal" user.

Now I'm stuck on calling the Api using volley. My API endpoint require a first login using json request with username and password to obtain the Bearer token required for the other calls.
I’m looking for documentation around but all examples are related to call inside the LoginActivity, nothing use a more complex structure like the one created by Android studio.

I want retain the clean solutions that use "LoginDataSource" as login central point, but I can't find a way to pass it as callback for the volley onResult.

I did some test, but I can't find a way to handle the async call result as return for the function.

Below is my current LoginDataSource :

```
/**
 * Class that handles authentication w/ login credentials and retrieves user information.
 */
public class LoginDataSource {

    private static final String API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN = "https://test.endpoint.com/login";

    Result<LoggedInUser> result;
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {
        try {
            final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            if (Objects.equals(response, "OK")) {
                                LoggedInUser user = new LoggedInUser(
                                        java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                                        username);
                                result = new Result.Success<>(user);
                            } else {
                                result = new Result.Error(new IOException("Check ID or password"));
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            result = new Result.Error(error);
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email", username);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getInstance());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
        return
    }

    public void logout() {
        // TODO: revoke authentication
    }

}
```

So, my questions are:

- How can I fix my code to handle this problem?
- **[SOLVED]** There is way to not use the context when I call Volley.newRequestQueue() ? I had to add the context parameter to the original login function but is pretty ugly because I must pass it manually

I found a way to solve this problem using "MyApplication" approach I just updated the code to reflect this solution

[FIRST UPDATE - ADDED MyApplication]

I change the manifest adding:

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Below the "MyApplication.java":

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = MyApplication.this;
    }


    public static MyApplication getInstance()
    {
        return sInstance;
    }
    
}
```